# Does Cons List have the property of a heap-allocated data or stack-allocated data?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers

From Rust Programming Language Book chapter 15 list 15-5, it uses `Box<T>` for indirection so type List's size could be known by Rust compiler.

To my understand, in the following example, Cons(1, address_x) is stack-allocated, Cons(2, address_y) &  Cons(3, address_z) are heap-allocated.

I am wondering when a variable has both stack-allocated data and heap-allocated data, does it have both of the data's property? I.e. does variable `list` has the property of stack-allocated data or heap-allocated data (like having copy trait pre-implemented) in this case?

- address_x points to Cons(2, address_y)
- address_y points to Cons(3, address_z)

```
enum List {
    Cons(i32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    let list = Cons(1, Box::new(Cons(2, Box::new(Cons(3, Box::new(Nil))))));
}
```

Comment: If all you want to know is whether `List` implements the `Copy` trait, you may just create a dummy function `fn test_copy<T: Copy>(t: T) {}` and use the compiler to test `test_copy(list)`.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki `Copy` trait is just an example, I am expecting a more general answer, i.e. the "property" of list

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since it misused the edit feature by turning a question into a completely different one and also rendered the existing answer invalid. If you think my thinking was wrong, you can roll back my rollback - but in this case, please explain how this question is the same as the original one. If you choose to not roll back, you should explain what do you mean by the "properties" - I understand `Copy` is not your main interest, what is?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The question I want to ask is what's the pros and cons of having some of the data stored in heap, which is the reason why I asked what's the difference between the property on two. Both of them are a general question so I gave an example that I could come up with like `Copy`, but it seems to lead to the wrong direction. Would you suggest I open a new question and leave this one as it be?

Comment: "What are the pros and cons" may be too vague for an SO question. Or may not. If you clarify enough, it may be on-topic. I'd suggest you to ask on https://meta.stackoverflow.com what to do.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh, didn't know there is such a tool. Thank you!
I'll now close this question then.

Comment: Yes, we really should present Meta better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the first `Cons` (the parent one) is stack allocated, all the others are heap allocated as per the `Boxing` wrapper you use on them.

Then:

> I am wondering does variable list has the property of stack-allocated data or heap-allocated data in this case?

Since it owns the first `Const` it is stack based too.

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/variables.html):

> A variable is a component of a stack frame, either a named function
> parameter, an anonymous temporary, or a named local variable.
>
> A local variable (or stack-local allocation) holds a value directly,
> allocated within the stack's memory. The value is a part of the stack
> frame.

About the trait question: **Varibles are just identifiers** data is what holds the properties. Hence whatever property the `List` datatype holds is what you will be able to use from a variable owning it.

Answer (score 1):

Types are not "stack allocated" or "heap allocated". They may be allocated in a variety of different ways, and are completely agnostic to their underlying storage.

- In `let list = List::Nil`, the list is allocated on the stack.
- In `let list = Box::new(List::Nil)`, the list is allocated on the heap.
- In `static list: List = List::Nil`, the list is allocated in the program's data section.